# Trouble with complex multi-line regular expression

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to parse large log in python using complex regular expression.
The sequence I am looking for is on multiple consecutive lines and can have positive or negative outcome. Here is the regex with test data:

Here is my problem: https://regex101.com/r/pF3eM6/1

The regex does what it should, pulling Start and end date, source and target format, job ID and completion time or "Time out". However when the sequence is not complete (like end of file), the expression ends up in error (try to delete the last line). I would like the expression simply ignore such sequence (no match).

And for completeness, here the same regex with "Time Out" variant of the log file - and the same problem as above.
https://regex101.com/r/pF3eM6/2

Can someone help me understand what and why is happening?

Comment: As regex101.com tells you, you are getting "catastrophic backtracking". You'll need to look up why that can happen, and what it is in your regexp that can lead to it.  http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had to rewrite it completely, I read the articles at http://regular-expressions.info and I finally understand how regex does work :)
For posterity, here is the commented solution:
https://regex101.com/r/pF3eM6/8